# I would like a self-contained, non–Al Amarja Over The Edge adventure

Tags: game-recommendation, published-adventures, over-the-edge, warp

I would like to use the Over The Edge rules (I have access to both the original game and the [WaRP rules](http://www.atlas-games.com/warp/)) to experiment with remote gaming (either via chat, email or some of the [dedicated stuff](http://rpgvirtualtabletop.wikidot.com/choosing-a-vt)).

I am also trying to reduce my effort to the minimum, so I am looking for a self-contained, premade adventure. By "self-contained" I mean something that does not require too much knowledge of a specific game milieu. So for example, I suppose that an Unknown Armies scenario could be a good choice (both systems are not too detailed mechanically, and share a surrealist approach), but I don't have the game manual with me at the moment, and I don't want players to have to sit through too much explanations about the universe.

I am familiar with most, if not all, supplements and adventures originally published for OTE. I'd prefer to go for something completely divorced from the "canonical" Al Amarja setting for two reasons:

- one is because of that "I am familiar with most..." — i.e. I want something completely new to me as a GM
- the second is that, even if this will probably remain an one-shot experiment, I am not completely sure that it won't blossom in a campaign — if that is the case, I don't want to be tied to Al Amarja

Finally, I am far from home ATM, so I'd really prefer something digitally available (I don't mean "free", just something I can get online, as in RPGNow).

Answer (score -1):

It Waits.  It could work in any city, anywhere on the planet.

Comment: Welcome to Role-playing Games! Please take a look at the [tour] and the [help]; they're a useful introduction to the site. Could you add some information about whether this is available electronically, and give us an idea of the content of the adventure?

Answer (score -1):

There are two WaRP-specific non-Al Amarja adventures on the Atlas Games WaRP page: http://www.atlas-games.com/warp/.

Comment: Noted, thanks! It's a pity nobody is using WARP :(

Comment: I want to run a time travel game with it.